# Google Tag Manager API error "Not a valid origin for the client: http://localhost has not been whitelisted for client ID

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-tag-manager, google-oauth

I'm trying to get started using the Google Tag Manager API. Does anyone know why I'm seeing the following error in my console even though I have added `http://localhost` and `http://localhost:8080` to the Authorised JavaScript origins in the API Credentials page?

> details: "Not a valid origin for the client: http://localhost has not
>   been whitelisted for client ID xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com .
>   Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this
>   origin for your project's client ID." error:
>   "idpiframe_initialization_failed"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is absolute **possible** to test in localhost.

**1)** Activate both Analytics and Google Tag Manager APIs on your project
**2)** Create new OAUTH 2.0 client credentials
**3)** Add the Authorized Javascript Origins under Restrictions section
**4)** Use the new client id.

The problem often occurs when you use client key instead of client id, make sure youre not mixing em.

Edit: Try to empty cache