# Google Spreadsheets API & localhost

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api

I try to follow this :
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js
to learn how to use the Google Spreadsheets API.
I have been careful to follow the directions but I must have missed something, since I get the following result :

```
    "error": "idpiframe_initialization_failed",
  "details": "Not a valid origin for the client: http://localhost:8000 has not been registered for client ID <YOUR_CLIENT_ID>. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and register this origin for your project's client ID."
```

I declared http://localhost to be authorised origin for my client_id ...
I tried in vain all the suggestions given here :
[Google Tag Manager API error "Not a valid origin for the client: http://localhost has not been whitelisted for client ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47608487/google-tag-manager-api-error-not-a-valid-origin-for-the-client-http-localhos)

Can someone tell me where this error might come from ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @taylor Thanks for your comment. The code I used is the one from "quickstart. I don't know what is different on my PC and thought one might have a clue form the error message.

Comment: Are you able to attach a link?